Como modificar un JSON en node js
estoy tratando de modificar un JSON para hacer un update en MSSQL
En mi controller tengo
const params = await Wsmssql.getInfo(nlic);
const parametros = JSON.parse(params.parametros);

Que me devuelve
{
   access: 'WXYZ',
   cve: '*********',
   ev: {
     Lic: '123456',
     IdResultado: '1',
     CURP: 'ABCD800601HNLFCH00',
     Nombre1: 'nombre1',
     Nombre2: 'nombre2',
     ApellidoP: 'apellidop',
     ApellidoM: 'apellidom',
     FechaE: '2024/05/09 15:25:00',
     IdTipoC: '2',
     IdTipoS: '2',
     LCveIden: 'Z',
     FolioC: '01234-AB-00'
   }
}

Lo que quiero hacer es modificar "LCveIden" solo me falta cambiar ese dato, para hacer el update del JSON

parametros.ev.LCvelden = newValue

muchas gracias no se porque me estaba complicando con el .find o each ya logre hacer mi update

Lo que devuelve JSON.parse no es un string json... es un objeto de JS normalito... Con lo cual, no hay ningún problema en modificarlo como cualquier otro objeto. Lo complicado sería modificar un json string obtenido mediante JSON.stringify en todo caso.
